# Controling switching regulator digitally

Tags: circuit-analysis, switching-regulator

I found this -piece- of schematic which is for controlling LM2596 output with a MCU, and I'm a bit confused:
[image]

- What is the purpose of those two schottky diodes? isn't it causing voltage drop which we have to compensate in software?
- How the opamp in voltage section works? and is it comparing `OUT+` with `OUT-` or `OUT-` as ground because of low-side current measurement?
- What's the `VCC` voltage for the voltage dividers next to the opamps? is it the same as `OUT+`?

<sup><sup>I found this schematic in Google images and it's not complete, please share the full schematic if you have it...</sup></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of those two schottky diodes? isn't it causing voltage drop which we have to compensate in software?

No, because the current and voltage are being by PI controllers; any offset from the diodes is compensated by their integral action.

> How the opamp in voltage section works, is it comparing OUT+ with OUT- or OUT- as ground because of low-side current measurement?

It is comparing OUT+ with OUT-.  OUT- is probably the actual output terminal of the supply (see where it's connected to R7).

> What's the VCC voltage for the voltage dividers next to the opamps? is it the same as OUT+?

VCC is generated somewhere else; it's almost certainly a clean reference voltage (or should be).  It would not be sensible for it to be OUT+.

Comment: Thanks, and what those schottky diodes are doing there? preventing two opamps output directly connect to each other? appreciate it if you please add some more details to the answer.

Comment: The diodes allow the current PI controller OR the voltage PI controller to limit the output voltage by raising the feedback voltage to the LM2596. The higher of the two provides the feedback voltage to the SMPS chip. The actual drop doesn't matter because of the integral characteristic. The unused one will tend to saturate near ground potential.

Comment: When I've done this sort of thing, I've put lead-lag (or PD, choose your terminology) controllers in front of the choose-maximum step (the diodes in this realization), followed by a pure integrator.  It makes for a much quicker, smoother transition because you don't have to wait for an integrator to wake up and realize it's being called to action.  It's easier to do in code than circuits, though.